# Power App - Trying to email address of field in lookup value

Tags: powerapps

I have 2 lists.  First list is called ICT Support Email App, and has a lookup Field ICT Division Name which Source is ICTDivList.  This second list has 2 fields - Title (which is ICT Division Name) and DivisionEmailAddress.  PowerApp works correctly - depending on what ICT Division Name I pick, it shows the correct DivisionEmailAddress.  Issue is that I want to email the DivisionEmailAddress once record is saved.  It never does show it on the form even though I have a field for it which confuses me. On Accept button (which is a checkmark on top of form), I have:

SubmitForm(AddForm1); Office365Outlook.SendEmail(DivisionEmailAddress, "Testing", "Services Requested:  " & AddForm1.LastSubmit.Title); If(AddForm1.ErrorKind = None, Navigate(Screen1,ScreenTransition.Fade))

If I put an actual email address in quotes where DivisionEmailAddress, it works.  What am I doing wrong??

Comment: You can save email address of user in one variable before `SubmitForm(AddForm1)`. Then you can use this variable to send an email.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a more elegant variant of Ganesh's solution (see his comment to your question) is to use this as address:

```
AddForm1.LastSubmit.ICTDivision.DivisionEmailAddress
```